# how to make functions global?

Tags: php, oop

i'm trying to follow DRY and i've got some functions i have to reuse.

i put them all as static functions in a class and want to use them in another class.

what is the best way to make them available to a class.

cause i can't extend the class, its already extended.

should/could i use composition?

what is best practice?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public class methods (vs instance methods, e.g. non-static) are always available from the global scope, so you could just call them statically where needed. But keep in mind that [static methods are death to testability](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/) and hard couple using classes to the [global scope](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/25/root-cause-of-singletons/) and the [used class](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/885-Stubbing-Hard-Coded-Dependencies.html). You want to avoid that, so it's better practise to get rid of the static methods in favor of instance methods and [passing in the dependency/object instance](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) through the constructor or a setter. Add an [interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) [Type Hint](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) if you want to make sure the passed instance has a certain set of methods.

Answer (score 4):

If they are static then just call them from your second class.

```
First_Class::method();
```